# Magnitude and direction of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

A ship is travelling at night in perfectly calm seas at a speed (relative to the
surrounding sea) of 40 km h−1 with a bearing of 120◦
. It is on course to enter
harbour in the morning assuming no change in the sea conditions.
Unfortunately, during the night, unknown to the crew, a strong current
arises, of 10 km h−1
in the direction from south-west to north-east

If the ship was 300 km from the harbour when the current arose and
heading at right angles to a shore that is approximately a straight line,
by how much will the ship miss the harbour because of the current?
Give your answer to the nearest km

?

Comment: I calculated the magnitude of the ships velocity as 44 in a direction of 107 degrees but am having a brain fog and would be grateful for fresh pair of eyes. Dont know how im finding such a simple question so difficult

Comment: What is the ship’s real velocity vector if you add in the current?